# iterating through a list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to multiple the numbers withing a list inside of another list

```
from itertools import combinations

target = random.randint(1,1000)
n_large = random.randint(0,4)
list_numbers = set()
large_numbs = [25,50,75,100]

while len(list_numbers)<n_large:
    n = random.choice(large_numbs)
    list_numbers.add(n)
while len(list_numbers)<10:
    n =random.randint(1,10)
    list_numbers.add(n)
list_numbers = sorted(list_numbers,reverse=True)

multi = list(combinations(list_numbers,2))



for i in multi:
    num_1 = (multi[i][0])*(multi[i][1])
```

However when I try to run it, it gives me the following error:

**TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple**

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `i` are the elements of the list, not indices. You could try enumerating, or simply `i[0] * i[1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last for loop:

```
for i in multi:
    num_1 = (multi[i][0])*(multi[i][1])
```

In this case, "i" is the value itself, it isn't the index. You can do it by typing instead:

```
num_1 = i[0] * i[1]
```

Or you can do the same using enumerate function:

```
for i, _ in enumerate(multi):
    num_1 = (multi[i][0])*(multi[i][1])
```